# Put a footer on a jqueryui autocomplete list

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I am attempting to put a footer on the list of an autocomplete. I am able to put another LI element in the list, but I can't get it to stay at the bottom.

I made a fiddle showing the basic HTML structure of the list. The problem is, with the CSS I have, the footer scrolls with the overflow area. How can I keep it pegged to the bottom?

http://jsfiddle.net/jCbPZ/1/

```
<ul>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
    <li>Item4</li>
    <li>Item5</li>
    <li>Item6</li>
    <li>Item7</li>
    <li>Item8</li>
    <li>Item9</li>
    <li>Item10</li>
    <li class="footer">Footer</li>
</ul>

ul{
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}

li.footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: gray;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: It's a css problem, or you are searching a solution using jQuery UI autocomplete?

Comment: It's part of jqueryui autocomplete, so if I can solve it another way, I'm open to it. If I can solve it with just CSS, that is fine too.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. The footer should remain visible all the time, not just when you scroll to the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Demo here..](http://jsfiddle.net/jCbPZ/16/)**

**Based on your update:**

EDIT: My demo works exactly how you want it to, try it out.. the position of the footer is absolutely relative to the list, and content outside of the list has no effect on it, as it previous did, I achieve this by setting a top margin. Problem solved.

```
li.footer {
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:100px;
    background: gray;
    color:white;
}
```

**Also removed the relative attribute in the ul.**

Comment: Fixed is absolute relative to the page. The lists aren't always going to be laid out in exactly the same spot: http://jsfiddle.net/jCbPZ/13/

Comment: Yeah, I was just extracting out the important parts. I will have pages with multiple lists. jQuery autocomplete automatically shows, hides, and positions the ul's, so a CSS solution would have to be a list element in the ul. I don't know if I can control a separate unrelated element.

Comment: It looks great in the fiddle. I tried to apply this to the site, and unfortunately I can't remove the position on the list. The list actually has position:absolute because the jquery autocomplete uses absolute positioning to place the list below an input element. I like this margin-top idea though, and I'll see if I can't make that work somehow.

Comment: I accepted this answer, because it works for the fiddle. I ended up having to take a slightly different approach. I wanted the footer because I am limiting results to 100 items and the footer would say "Refine search for more results". Since I couldn't get that to work within the limitations of the HTML used by jquery autocomplete, I placed that text as the first list item (with a different background color) and it's a pretty good compromise.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can approach the problem with a different point of view.

You can extend the widget autocomplete plugin, and add a custom footer to the autocomplete list by overriding the `_renderMenu` function.

Code:

```
$(function () {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"];

    $.widget("custom.autocompletefooter", $.ui.autocomplete, {
        _renderMenu: function (ul, items) {
            var self = this;
            $.each(items, function (index, item) {
                self._renderItem(ul, item);
                if (index == items.length - 1) ul.append('<li class="footer-auto"> Footer of autocomplete!!</li>');
            });
        }
    });

    $("#tags").autocompletefooter({
        source: availableTags
    });

});
```

Docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/ykbrS/

Comment: I may end up needing to do something like this and override the *menu* property so it adds a div around the ul.

Comment: I read now that the footer must be fixed, I provide a demo when possible

Answer (score 0):

You can just position the `bottom` of the `footer` as :

```
li.footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -100;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: gray;
    color: white;
}
```

See the fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/jCbPZ/7/

Answer (score 0):

Use a wrapper div and a div for the footer instead of an li.

HTML

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>Item1</li>
        <li>Item2</li>
        <li>Item3</li>
        <li>Item4</li>
        <li>Item5</li>
        <li>Item6</li>
        <li>Item7</li>
        <li>Item8</li>
        <li>Item9</li>
        <li>Item10</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
ul{
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom:0;
}

div.footer{
    background: gray;
    color: white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vBQEm/

Comment: I wish I could do this, but I would end up having to change the jqueryui autocomplete code to add the divs.

Answer (score 0):

Why position the last list element at all? It will inherently be positioned at the bottom of the list.

```
li.footer{
    background: gray;
    color: white;
}
```

You can see this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jCbPZ/11/) for example.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. The footer should remain visible all the time, not just when you scroll to the bottom.